# How to limit the frequency of pushing of keys in the BGE?

Tags: game-engine

I want to limit frequency of possible pushing of keyboard buttons in a game so that the player would not be able to push a button more often than two times a second. Pulse modes seem not to work, because they deal with constant signals, and pushing a button several times is not a constant signal, so I don't know what to use here.

Comment: try enabling "Tap" on the actuator.

Comment: I tried to enable "Tap" in the keyboard sensor, but it seems to change to negative one frame after receiving positive signal only if positive signal is constant. And if player will push a button five times a second, the sensor will send true-signals all five times - they are not constant. I need maximum two true signals a second, no meter how many times he/she will push a button during that period.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have simple Python script:

```
import bge
from bge import logic

REFRESH_RATE = 60

cont = logic.getCurrentController()
owner = cont.owner

owner["timer"] += 1

keyboard = bge.logic.keyboard
JUST_ACTIVATED = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED

if keyboard.events[bge.events.SPACEKEY] == JUST_ACTIVATED:
    if owner["pressed"] < 2:
        owner["toggle"] = not owner["toggle"]
        owner["pressed"] += 1
if owner["timer"] >= REFRESH_RATE/2:
    owner["timer"] = 0
    owner["pressed"] = 0
```

`toggle` property is used here just to present the effect of the mechanism, it changes if the user input is accepted. Keep in mind that the `REFRESH_RATE` should be the same as the one stored in Render Properties. 
The Logic Editor setup in this case would be:
[image]

You can also download it as .blend file here:
[image]
I hope this can help you solve the problem. Cheers.

Comment: I tried the script, it works in common, but needs to be adjusted for my situation. So I will learn python basics or cooperate with a programmer to lead my goal.
Thank you very much, Krzysztof!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use the build-in state machine.

**State graph**

Your state graph is pretty simple. You need just two states:

[image]

1. *accepting input* - this is when it waits that the user presses `<w>`
2. *cooling down* - this is when it measures the time till the user can press `<w>` again.

**Transitions**

A possible implementation the transition from state *accepting input* is:
[image]
An keyboard sensor triggers a controller which activates a state change to state *cooling down*

A possible implementation of the transition from state *accepting input* is:
[image]
An delay sensor triggers a controller which activates a state change to state *accepting input*

**Action**

You need to add the action to be done that should happen after pressing `<w>`. Action regarding state machines are operations (not to be confused with actions regarding Blender which are animations).

Dependent on the operation(s) you can implement them

... as **ExitAction** of *accepting input*. You can activate further actuators connected to the same controller that activate the state change. This is good when the operation lasts one frame only.
[image]

... as **EntryAction** of *accepting input*. In that case you use an always sensor with [Level] enabled triggering any controller you like. This is good when the operation lasts one frame only and the previous state does not matter.
[image]

... as **StateAction** of *cooling down*. In that case you use an always sensor triggering any controller you like. optional you can enable [True Level Triggering]. This is good when the operation lasts longer than a frame but not longer than the state.
[image]

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Monster!
This way is much more convenient for me as a non-pythonic approach :j