# How do I make it so something will go when collected, then re-spawn after awhile?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

So in Game Engine, I have been trying to make an empty that after a message gets sent, AND after 30 seconds, the object will come back, but as I can see, the message only sends once, and the logic brick does not remember it being sent, so after 30 seconds, the message isn't there. Is there any better ways to do this, or any way to make the message sensor remember that it has been sent
The message is for, when it gets deleted, it gets sent to an empty to spawn there, but I want it after 30 seconds

Comment: I think you can go with the same solution as asked in [How to limit the frequency of pushing of keys in the BGE?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33151) It is a timing issue too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle objects.

- On request the visible object can remove itself and adds another invisible object that counts the 60s. 
  [image]
- After timeout the invisible object deletes itself and adds the visible object again.
  [image]

As you can only add objects from an invisible layer and you want to re-add your objects, I suggest to start with an empty that immediately adds the visible object. This "startup" empty is not needed anymore and can end itself too.
[image]

Comment: ok, so this has worked, however, each time the item comes back, it is smaller than the last

Comment: This is because your objects scale is screwy, select both the object you want to spawn, and the invisible spawner object and [ctrl]+[a] > scale. that should solve everything.

Comment: Ah.. Thank you, it's working perfectly fine now